# Adwhirl - Millenial Ads - Unsupported ration type

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl, ads

this is my second question related to ads, i'm really sorry, I've searched the whole web for the last 2 weeks now, didn't find a solution, maybe together we find something :=)

With the use of **Adwhirl SDK** I'm n**ot able** to display ads **from any other ad network** than **AdMob**. 
Google Adsense gets this Error, Millenial Network gets it too, and also Google AdSense.
At least some of it should work.

It always says 'showing ad' but afterwards failure.
Nothing is showing at all. Also ad roation do not work. I'm really a little bit pi**ed of after so long, trying to get this to work. Feeling like the last idiot on the web. :=/

thanks!

```
11-16 16:26:35.676: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Unsupported ration type: 14
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Caught an exception in adapter:
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): java.lang.Exception: Invalid adapter
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:141)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:163)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:151)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:316)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
11-16 16:26:35.686: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Showing ad:
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     nid: 90728e67f6d94734a2669b1c15ebbfd9
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     name: zestadz
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     type: 20
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     key: 14131C047A50414xxxxxxxxxxxx ;=) 9
11-16 16:26:35.696: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     key2: 
11-16 16:26:35.696: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Unsupported ration type: 20
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Caught an exception in adapter:
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655): java.lang.Exception: Invalid adapter
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.adapters.AdWhirlAdapter.handle(AdWhirlAdapter.java:141)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.handleAd(AdWhirlLayout.java:163)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.access$3(AdWhirlLayout.java:151)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$HandleAdRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:316)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
11-16 16:26:35.706: WARN/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 16:26:35.706: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(15655): nextRation is null!
```

Millenial says a littlebit more:

```
   11-16 16:28:05.426: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Dart is <64.70737969255892> of <100.0>
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Showing ad:
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     nid: f47a7262bb3d4dbab6d3ab62ea1bada5
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     name: millennial
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     type: 6
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     key: 25264
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655):     key2: 
11-16 16:28:05.446: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Valid adapter, calling handle()
11-16 16:28:05.916: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(15655): Millennial failure


    11-16 16:23:29.466: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): New MMAdView Started
11-16 16:23:29.466: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): Activity: ActivityInfo{44c9c778 com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer}
11-16 16:23:29.476: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): Activity: ActivityInfo{44c7f458 com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdViewOverlayActivity}
11-16 16:23:29.476: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): Automatic ad fetching is off with -1. You must manually call for ads.
11-16 16:23:29.486: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): Calling for an advertisement: http://androidsdk.ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd.php5?sdkapid=25264&auid=357988021219469&ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android Tegro-2.1.3 (2.1-update1); de-at; HTC Hero Build/ERE27) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17HTC Hero&mmisdk=3.6.3-10.10.26.a&kw=android&mode=live&adtype=MMBannerAdTop
11-16 16:23:30.076: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): size: 0
11-16 16:23:30.076: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): num: 0
11-16 16:23:30.076: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(15655): Millennial ad return failed
```

Would be really thankful for any advice or help :=)
**Thanks!**

Comment: sorry, i though i checked it, but i solved this errors by adding the 2 (zestads, adsense sdks). now i always get 'next ration null' also no idea what this means.. .(

Comment: Do you know if AdWhirl are still alive? I get no responses in their forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make sure that "MillenialMedia" jar file is in the Java Build path?
I ran into the same issue and adding it to the Java Build Path fixed it for me.